# How to get function names from an compiled exe?

Tags: disassembly

So i am trying to get all of the function names from an exe using NM.

I am including NtRaiseHardError in my c++ exe, how can i get NtRaiseHardError using nm?

Is that possible?

And if yes how?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

However, If a file is NOT built with a symbol table (Debug options e.g  **-g**
), No one can export it. Try to disassembly it will just get its topology but not user-friendly symbols.

For *ELF* files you can simply use `nm [FILE]` to show its symbols

For *Windows PE* files use `DUMPBIN /Exports [FILE]` DUMPBIN is included in WIndows SDK

If your program including some symbols from DLL, you can exports DLL's symbols and use some trace debugger to watch what are fuctions exported from DLLs used.

Comment: When i try to use Dumpbin i get this: LINK: extra operand 'a.exe', i am using dumpbin /exports a.exe, why does this happen?